# Getting error only when using select top 1000 query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view `xyz_view` which has around 16,000 records.

There are four date columns which have data in this format `'2015-04-30 00:00:00.000'`

When I use query

```
select * 
from xyz_view
```

I get all the records without any problem but when I use

```
select top 1000 * 
from xyz_view
```

I get an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2013-08-05 00:00:00.0' to data type int.

Even `select top 100 * from xyz_view` works. Anything over 300 is throwing above error.

Please help me understand on this.

Comment: Please post the query that you are using.

Comment: When you just use `select *...` are you really getting all the records, or is your editor limiting the amount returned?

Comment: Are you querying a view or a table? Your question wording suggests you are looking at a view.

Comment: The error doesn't even mention `datetime`.  It says converting `varchar` to `int`.  Need to check the definition of the view.

Comment: @CaptainAdams: yes i am looking at a view.

Answer (score 0):

I think something in data type of four columns are not `datetime` type. Because your value is: `'2013-08-05 00:00:00.0'`

If is `datetime` type, it is: `'2013-08-05 00:00:00.000'` (3 numbers for milliseconds)

In view, you can convert or cast columns to datetime type, like this:

```
CAST(columns AS DATETIME)
CONVERT(DATETIME, columns)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your top < 1000 doesn't show an error because it doesn't fetch the row with erroneous data.

The error check is only running when you fetch the row where one of your column with data type `int` got a `date` value in it - `2013-08-05 00:00:00.0`

Check this record by running a `Select` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = '2013-08-05 00:00:00.0'
```

Base on the record you see, decide then if you would change the erroneous `2013-08-05 00:00:00.0` to any acceptable `int` value

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = 123
WHERE myColumn = '2013-08-05 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: What a terrible suggestion: just delete probably important data instead of figuring out the cause of the error!

Comment: How come a `Date` inside an `INT` column a probable important data? Even so, if you read again I did say that he should make sure to `Select` the record in question first before doing the `Update`.

Comment: without knowing the data, you have no way of knowing whether it is necessary.  A good starting assumption, however, is that people actually need the data they have stored.  Furthermore, *as a matter of principle* this is the wrong way to debug an error.  It may make the error go away, but you haven't learned anything about the underlying cause of the error, and that means it is likely to recur in the future (such as when more data is loaded).

Comment: @CurseStacker: but select * (without top) query contains the erroneous data and not throwing an error.

Comment: @curiousboy, as for your question, it cannot be answered without you showing us the view code.